# How do I get to the Chrome address bar with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

I used to be able to use <kbd>F6</kbd> to get to the address bar (omnibox) on Chrome. Maybe it's platform dependent, as I'm on a Mac. But I'd like to know if there's a different keyboard shortcut I can use or a setting I can configure to achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut for jumping to the address bar is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en-GB

Comment: Awesome! Works in Safari too :).

Comment: And in Windows this is Ctrl-L on all browsers I use.